# Fetch data from Sqllite having comma separated values in column

Tags: android, database, sqlite

The requirement is simple I need to get the rows having exactly '4' in it but the problem is that in Sqllite there is no FIND_IN_SET function.I am trying to get the values using LIKE Query:

The code snippets I have tried

```
select * from tbl_opportunity where (',' || opp_Business_id || ',') LIKE ',4,%'
```

but it is returning only 2 rows and sometimes also more if the row contains  '24,' or any number having data like this '4,'

[image: Table Structure of tbl_opportunity]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite does support regular expressions `WHERE opp_Business_id REGEXP "\b" || 4 || "\b";` - otherwise you would need to match for all possible combinations. that your pattern does not match the least should be obvious, when it fails 2/3 of the example records; `WHERE (opp_Business_id == '4' OR opp_Business_id LIKE '%,4' OR opp_Business_id LIKE '4,%' OR opp_Business_id LIKE '%,4,%');` that would be four comparisons with `LIKE` - vs. only one with `REGEXP`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about Android platform and `Android's Sqlite` doesn't support `REGEXP` keyword. You have to write your query like this [I used Room syntax for better understanding]:

```
@Query(
    "SELECT * FROM tbl_opportunity WHERE " +
            "(" +
            "',' || opp_Business_id || ',' LIKE '%' || :businessId || ',%' OR " +
            "',' || opp_Business_id || ',' LIKE '%' || :businessId OR " +
            "',' || opp_Business_id || ',' LIKE :businessId || '%'" +
            ") "
)
suspend fun getByBusinessId(businessId: Int): List<Opportunity>
```